# How did I get noticed as an active and highly reputed user?

Tags: discussion, users

I received an email from an Indian PhD student in Austria (looks real), where for his research he needs interviews with ***active*** and high reputed (the first characteristic is true).

My [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300) is *not even accepted* and 2 years old. My [top question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614396/what-does-i-i-i-1-1-do) 1 year old.

I am trying to figure out how he landed on my profile. I mean when someone goes to "Users" on the top right of SO, he will find giants, in terms of reputation..*So I guess he was able to determine somehow I am active and with a (relatively, above the average) high reputation. Wonder how...*

Notice that my top answer has also received an upvote.

Comment: How do you know he didn't contact all of those people (assuming their contact information was available)? :-(

Comment: Because that would be **many** people Cody Gray, I guess.. ;) But yes, he might have spent many days to do so, that would be an explanation...But if there is a way to find the "active" users in SO, then sorting them by rep would be easy. My title was like a spy-007 style, but good edit!

Comment: @gsamaras *"But if there is a way to find the "active" users in SO"* [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) could probably get that by filtering for LastAccessDate. if you want to exclude those trying to get the fanatic badge by just showing up you can do an inner join to the posts

Comment: @Memor-X didn't know about Data Explorer, that can serve as an answer...I really hope that this was the case though, and not what Cody G said! :)))

Comment: Could have looked at one of the reputation leagues sorted by month for example too http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow where your rank is higher than your all time rank.

Comment: Well, you have the email address of this person, why not ask them? :)

Comment: Because @MikeMcCaughan he turns out to request many info! :)

Comment: Austria is not the same as Australia ;-)

Comment: Oh @Carpetsmoker that might explain the -5 I got! :P Anyway, the guy was cool after all.. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Assuming it's the same person I spoke today this morning, then it was a girl, not a guy ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's infer a few things here.

- You are a user who has above 10K reputation, a feat which (as of the time of writing) only about 10,000 users have accomplished.
- You have a high-scoring answer, something that has been done about 20,000 times with users above 10K reputation.
- **You have your contact information in your profile, if you follow a few links.**
- Let's be honest, many people consider 3K "high rep" here; I would personally peg that at closer to 5K, but "high" is a moving target.

Let's say that you were one of the lucky handful to be picked that could actually be reached.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "lucky" I guess...

Comment: Yeah @NinjaPuppy...let's just say that I'd rather disqualify myself from such a prize.

Comment: What is the definition of a high-scoring answer?  Above 100 plus votes total?

Comment: @PeterMortensen:  I'd say that "high scoring" could be as high as 10, but for the sake of the query I ran last night, I had it capped at 100+.