# Surprising interview proposal

Tags: discussion, spam

I received an e-mail (lifted from my home page I'm linking to in my Stack Overflow profile) from someone proposing to interview me. Let me share it with you:

> Hi Jean,
>
> I found your contact information from StackOverflow and saw that you are an active member with a good reputation over 7000 …
>
> I am (name withheld) and I am doing my PhD at Queensland University of Technology. I am doing research on user engagement on co-creation networks. For the purpose of my research, I need to interview people who are actively using StackOverflow. Your high contribution on StackOverflow makes you an ideal candidate for my study.
>
> Would you be interested in undertaking an interview over Skype about your participation on Stack Overflow? You can read more here: (some link).   Please contact me if you are keen : ) Thank you

Now my questions:

- Is that common practice to do such interviews?
- "ideal candidate": did other people have such proposals?
- Should I accept?

I confirm that this is not spam. It seems legit.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this person for more information - the email address of a professor or supervisor. It sure sounds an interesting topic to me.

Comment: I've never received one (I'd be shocked if I did in any regard), but I don't think it is all that uncommon as I've seen similar questions on meta about such contact.  These "survey" requests have been spammed in chat before, and users occasionally post the survey on both the main site and on meta to get participatants

Comment: Related: [Spam being mailed mentioning Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308236/spam-being-mailed-mentioning-stack-overflow)

Comment: I got one too, I usually get several solicitations like that a year.  Academia is fascinated by SO, they all want to find out how to get geeks to supply expert advice for no money.  They are not nearly as fascinated by each others research on the exact same topic it seems, gets old.  I never once participated, let's keep it a secret.

Comment: This sounds remarkably like [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333926/how-did-i-get-noticed-as-an-active-and-highly-reputed-user)

Comment: @JonClements: Indian PhD student in Austria (looks real): that's him!! Well, let's not mix up Austria (mother country of Arnold) and Australia (mother country of Mel). It's Australia.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think Jon said it was him.  He said it was similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really wouldn't read too much into it; the likely scenario (which you allude to) is that your profile had readily accessible contact information in it, and someone used that to contact you.

Whether or not you accept is entirely your decision.

Comment: This. A surprising number of people do research and/or surveys based on SO contact information; if you get one, just make a decision about it. You don't have to accept.